# Write in JSON File in a specific position in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, json, append

I need a little help (I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but i'm a beginner and I have tried to solve my problem several times without success...)

I would like to write in a specific position in a JSON file for example, add a new score to Sarah (id 2)

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"Josh","score":["100","150","50"]},
{"id":2,"name":"Sarah","score":["150","200","200"]},
{"id":3,"name":"Thomas","score":["10","100","150"]},
]
```

To

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"Josh","score":["100","150","50"]},
{"id":2,"name":"Sarah","score":["150","200","200","300"]},
{"id":3,"name":"Thomas","score":["10","100","150"]},
]
```

Comment: You can use libraries like GSON or Jackson for example to turn your JSON into a java object, after which you can manipulate the java object easily and turn it back into JSON with GSON/Jackson/whatever

Comment: (1) Parse file content to JSON structure (here array of objects), (2) modify selected object, (3) write JSON structure back to file (replace its entire content).

Comment: Thanks you, so I tried to parse the string, but when i replace the content i get instead of " \" in my json file i don't know why

Comment: In JS , `json[1].score.push(300)`

Answer (score 2):

Import classes:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
```

Read all Json Objects from json file:

```
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("sample.json"))
    {
        //Read JSON file
        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
        JSONArray list= (JSONArray) obj;  

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now do modification in list by iterating it:

```
int count = list.length(); // get totalCount of all jsonObjects
            for(int i=0 ; i< count; i++){   // iterate through jsonArray 
                JSONObject jsonObject = list.getJSONObject(i);  // get jsonObject @ i position 
            }
```

Write it again in json file:

```
  try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("sample.json")) {
        file.write(list.toJSONString());
        file.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I have some error : "cannot find symbol JSONParser" for example, i'm compiling with "javac -cp "json-simple-1.1.1.jar" test.java" i don't know why i got this message